# How to determine HKQuantitySample quantityType?

Tags: ios, objective-c, healthkit

I am trying to determine what kind of HKQuantityTypeIdentifier matches the measurements provided in a particular Health Kit sample To determine this, I have tried the following:

```
if(hkSample.quantityType == HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDistanceCycling) ...

if([hkSample.quantityType isEqual: HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDistanceCycling]) ...
```

and

```
if([hkSample.quantityType isEqualToString: HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDistanceCycling]) ...
```

The first two options run but give a negative result even when the types should be matching and the last option gives a run-time NSException error for an unknown method. What's the proper way to determine which type maths an HKQuantitySample type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`quantityType` is an HKQuantityType, not a string, so it doesn’t respond to `-isEqualToString:`. You need to compare it with another HKQuantityType via `-isEqual:`, like this:

```
if ([hkSample.quantityType isEqual:[HKQuantityType quantityTypeForIdentifier:HKQuantityTypeIdentifierDistanceCycling]])
```